# Create a service GlassFish

Tags: glassfish

I have a problem starting glassfishs service in windows 8.1

I got this error :

`c:\glassfishv3\bin>asadmin create-service`

```
Found the Windows Service and successfully uninstalled it.
WMI.WmiException: AccessDenied
   at WMI.WmiRoot.BaseHandler.CheckError(ManagementBaseObject result)
   at WMI.WmiRoot.ClassHandler.Invoke(Object proxy, MethodInfo method, Object[]
args)
   at WMI.Win32ServicesProxy.Create(String , String , String , ServiceType , Err
orControl , StartMode , Boolean , String[] )
   at winsw.WrapperService.Run(String[] args)
   at winsw.WrapperService.Main(String[] args)
Error while trying to install GlassFish as a Windows Service.
The return value was: 2.
STDERR:
STDOUT: WMI.WmiException: AccessDenied
   at WMI.WmiRoot.BaseHandler.CheckError(ManagementBaseObject result)
   at WMI.WmiRoot.ClassHandler.Invoke(Object proxy, MethodInfo method, Object[]
args)
   at WMI.Win32ServicesProxy.Create(String , String , String , ServiceType , Err
orControl , StartMode , Boolean , String[] )
   at winsw.WrapperService.Run(String[] args)
   at winsw.WrapperService.Main(String[] args)

Usage: asadmin [asadmin-utility-options] create-service [--name <name>]
        [--serviceproperties <serviceproperties>]
        [--dry-run[=<dry-run(default:false)>]] [--domaindir <domaindir>]
        [-?|--help[=<help(default:false)>]] [domain_name]
Command create-service failed.
```

The user account is administrator.

I dont know what to do,Could you give me a recomendation to solve this error.

Answer (score 2):

Your account may be an administrator however did you launch the cmd/shell "As Administrator"? Good old windows UAC.

I had this problem and had to right click on the cmd.exe/Command Prompt and select "Run as administrator"

Then run the: asadmin create-service --name "Glassfish YourDomainName" YourDomainName